# what is the source of Sivakalpataru mantra?

Tags: shiva, reference-request

I can remember only a few lines. Prabhumisha manisham ashesha gunam. Gunahina Mahisha Garabharanam. Rananirjita Durjaya Daitya puram Pranamami Sivam Siva Kalpatarum. What is the source of this bhajan/mantra?

Comment: Even I've heard them, but I don't seem to recall where....

Comment: I don't know where it's from, but here's the [full](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Nitya_Pooja/Nl5QDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA91&printsec=frontcover) version...

Comment: @CDR Thank you so much for sharing the book link.